# Unstability with network card on HP Zbook

Tags: wireless, firmware

I purchased a new HP Zbook and installed Ubuntu 22.04 on it.
I have recurring unstabilities with Wifi card.
The Wireless card model is : Intel(R) Wifi 6E AX211 160 Mhz
At the beginning, adapter the did not show up.
Now adapter shows up but I have many issues.

After some time the PC gets completely stuck. I investigated in the log and I found following error message :

```
[   88.270463] warning: `iwconfig' uses wireless extensions which will stop working for Wi-Fi 7 hardware; use nl80211
```

So I tried to reconfigure the adapter using iw instead as iwconfig as it is suggested in some blogs. However, when doing that it does not work and I get a lot of messages in the log :

```
[  965.742248] CPU: 6 PID: 531 Comm: kworker/6:2 Tainted: P        W  OE      6.5.0-15-generic #15~22.04.1-Ubuntu
[  965.742255] Hardware name: HP HP ZBook Firefly 16 inch G10 Mobile Workstation PC/8B41, BIOS V70 Ver. 01.03.00 10/26/2023
[  965.742259] Workqueue: events cfg80211_conn_work [cfg80211]
[  965.742458] Call Trace:
[  965.742461]  <TASK>
[  965.742466]  dump_stack_lvl+0x48/0x70
[  965.742476]  dump_stack+0x10/0x20
[  965.742484]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd_sync+0x1d5/0x370 [iwlwifi]
[  965.742560]  ? __pfx_autoremove_wake_function+0x10/0x10
[  965.742569]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd+0xb8/0x170 [iwlwifi]
[  965.742627]  iwl_trans_send_cmd+0x81/0x110 [iwlwifi]
[  965.742684]  iwl_mvm_send_cmd+0x38/0xa0 [iwlmvm]
[  965.742755]  iwl_mvm_reg_scan_start+0x30a/0x420 [iwlmvm]
[  965.742826]  iwl_mvm_mac_hw_scan+0x50/0x80 [iwlmvm]
[  965.742874]  drv_hw_scan+0xbc/0x180 [mac80211]
[  965.743020]  __ieee80211_start_scan+0x28e/0x6a0 [mac80211]
[  965.743136]  ieee80211_request_scan+0x30/0x60 [mac80211]
[  965.743251]  ieee80211_scan+0x66/0x110 [mac80211]
[  965.743384]  cfg80211_conn_scan+0x18e/0x470 [cfg80211]
[  965.743509]  ? lock_timer_base+0x3b/0xe0
[  965.743515]  cfg80211_conn_do_work+0x153/0x4d0 [cfg80211]
[  965.743639]  cfg80211_conn_work+0xeb/0x170 [cfg80211]
[  965.743751]  ? __wake_up_common_lock+0x8b/0xd0
[  965.743759]  ? __wake_up_common_lock+0x8b/0xd0
[  965.743765]  ? __wake_up+0x13/0x30
[  965.743771]  ? netlink_broadcast+0x115/0x1a0
[  965.743780]  ? nl80211_send_scan_msg+0x3e/0x80 [cfg80211]
[  965.743885]  ? ___cfg80211_scan_done+0x23d/0x280 [cfg80211]
[  965.743983]  ? finish_task_switch.isra.0+0x85/0x2a0
[  965.743989]  process_one_work+0x23d/0x450
[  965.743995]  worker_thread+0x50/0x3f0
[  965.744000]  ? __pfx_worker_thread+0x10/0x10
[  965.744004]  kthread+0xef/0x120
[  965.744010]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[  965.744015]  ret_from_fork+0x44/0x70
[  965.744022]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[  965.744027]  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
[  965.744032]  </TASK>
[  965.744054] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Scan failed! ret -5
[  965.744159] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  965.744161] WARNING: CPU: 6 PID: 5092 at net/mac80211/scan.c:423 __ieee80211_scan_completed+0x31e/0x340 [mac80211]
[  965.744273] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm snd_ctl_led snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_sof_probes snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac ledtrig_audio algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel snd_sof_intel_hda_mlink soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp intel_uncore_frequency snd_sof intel_uncore_frequency_common bnep snd_sof_utils snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_bus snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus joydev snd_pcm_dmaengine x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_intel coretemp snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec kvm_intel snd_hda_core snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41_spi snd_hwdep snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41_i2c snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41 snd_hda_cs_dsp_ctls nvidia_uvm(POE) snd_pcm kvm cs_dsp snd_soc_cs35l41_lib iwlmvm uvcvideo snd_seq_midi videobuf2_vmalloc irqbypass
[  965.744341]  nvidia_drm(POE) pmt_telemetry uvc mei_pxp mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr pmt_class nvidia_modeset(POE) binfmt_misc videobuf2_memops snd_seq_midi_event crct10dif_pclmul i915 videobuf2_v4l2 snd_rawmidi mac80211 polyval_clmulni btusb libarc4 polyval_generic btrtl snd_seq ghash_clmulni_intel drm_buddy aesni_intel btbcm ttm crypto_simd videodev snd_seq_device drm_display_helper btintel cryptd cmdlinepart hp_wmi input_leds snd_timer rapl spi_nor cdc_mbim btmtk iwlwifi videobuf2_common nvidia(POE) cec nls_iso8859_1 intel_cstate serio_raw platform_profile wmi_bmof mtd cdc_wdm hid_multitouch bluetooth snd mc processor_thermal_device_pci cfg80211 mei_me rc_core processor_thermal_device 8250_dw soundcore ecdh_generic mei ecc processor_thermal_rfim processor_thermal_mbox drm_kms_helper processor_thermal_rapl i2c_algo_bit intel_rapl_common intel_vsec serial_multi_instantiate int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone intel_hid int3400_thermal sparse_keymap acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad acpi_tad mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc
[  965.744430]  ppdev lp parport drm efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid cdc_ncm cdc_ether usbnet mii spi_pxa2xx_platform hid_generic dw_dmac dw_dmac_core nvme crc32_pclmul thunderbolt i2c_i801 intel_lpss_pci spi_intel_pci nvme_core xhci_pci spi_intel intel_lpss i2c_smbus ucsi_acpi idma64 xhci_pci_renesas nvme_common typec_ucsi typec i2c_hid_acpi i2c_hid video hid wmi pinctrl_tigerlake
[  965.744478] CPU: 6 PID: 5092 Comm: kworker/u24:1 Tainted: P        W  OE      6.5.0-15-generic #15~22.04.1-Ubuntu
[  965.744482] Hardware name: HP HP ZBook Firefly 16 inch G10 Mobile Workstation PC/8B41, BIOS V70 Ver. 01.03.00 10/26/2023
[  965.744485] Workqueue: phy0 ieee80211_scan_work [mac80211]
[  965.744593] RIP: 0010:__ieee80211_scan_completed+0x31e/0x340 [mac80211]
[  965.744700] Code: 0f 00 48 85 c0 74 0c 48 8b 78 08 4c 89 fe e8 a9 2d 05 00 65 ff 0d aa cf 6d 3b 0f 85 ab fe ff ff 0f 1f 44 00 00 e9 a1 fe ff ff <0f> 0b 48 83 c4 10 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 41 5f 5d 31 c0 31 d2 31 f6
[  965.744704] RSP: 0000:ffffaf1886e63d98 EFLAGS: 00010246
[  965.744708] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000000
[  965.744710] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: ffff9c93d1d78900
[  965.744713] RBP: ffffaf1886e63dd0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[  965.744715] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000001
[  965.744717] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff9c93c9ca2b00 R15: ffff9c93d1d78900
[  965.744719] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9c9b37780000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  965.744722] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  965.744724] CR2: 00007f1f873122e8 CR3: 00000006fa83a000 CR4: 0000000000750ee0
[  965.744727] PKRU: 55555554
[  965.744729] Call Trace:
[  965.744731]  <TASK>
[  965.744732]  ? show_regs+0x6d/0x80
[  965.744740]  ? __warn+0x89/0x160
[  965.744746]  ? __ieee80211_scan_completed+0x31e/0x340 [mac80211]
[  965.744854]  ? report_bug+0x17e/0x1b0
[  965.744859]  ? handle_bug+0x46/0x90
[  965.744867]  ? exc_invalid_op+0x18/0x80
[  965.744872]  ? asm_exc_invalid_op+0x1b/0x20
[  965.744880]  ? __ieee80211_scan_completed+0x31e/0x340 [mac80211]
[  965.744987]  ieee80211_scan_work+0x16d/0x660 [mac80211]
[  965.745094]  ? __schedule+0x2d4/0x750
[  965.745100]  process_one_work+0x23d/0x450
[  965.745104]  worker_thread+0x50/0x3f0
[  965.745109]  ? __pfx_worker_thread+0x10/0x10
[  965.745112]  kthread+0xef/0x120
[  965.745118]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[  965.745123]  ret_from_fork+0x44/0x70
[  965.745128]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[  965.745133]  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
[  965.745137]  </TASK>
[  965.745139] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
[  966.234471] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
[  966.391076] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_UMAC_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x20
[  966.391125] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_LMAC2_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
[  966.391239] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0: 0x90
[  966.391292] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: CNVI_SCU_SEQ_DATA_DW9: 0x0
[  966.392520] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: RFIm is deactivated, reason = 4
[ 1033.803073] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[ 1033.803206] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[ 1033.803211] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004B, valid: 6
[ 1033.803215] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 83.e8f84e98.0 so-a0-gf-a0-83.ucode
[ 1033.803220] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
[ 1033.803224] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000002F0 | trm_hw_status0
[ 1033.803227] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[ 1033.803229] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004DB338 | branchlink2
[ 1033.803232] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004D088E | interruptlink1
[ 1033.803235] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004D088E | interruptlink2
[ 1033.803238] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000157E2 | data1
[ 1033.803240] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000010 | data2
[ 1033.803243] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
[ 1033.803245] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[ 1033.803248] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0405BA3C | tsf low
[ 1033.803251] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[ 1033.803253] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[ 1033.803256] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0406FE53 | time gp2
[ 1033.803258] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[ 1033.803261] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000053 | uCode version major
[ 1033.803264] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE8F84E98 | uCode version minor
[ 1033.803267] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000370 | hw version
[ 1033.803269] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x18C80002 | board version
[ 1033.803272] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80E1FF00 | hcmd
[ 1033.803275] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00020000 | isr0
[ 1033.803277] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[ 1033.803280] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x48F04002 | isr2
[ 1033.803282] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C3000C | isr3
[ 1033.803285] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[ 1033.803287] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00240103 | last cmd Id
[ 1033.803290] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000157E2 | wait_event
[ 1033.803292] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[ 1033.803295] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[ 1033.803297] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[ 1033.803300] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[ 1033.803302] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000018 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[ 1033.803305] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[ 1033.803307] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000C8EC | flow_handler
[ 1033.803374] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[ 1033.803377] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004B, valid: 7
[ 1033.803380] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20103609 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[ 1033.803383] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[ 1033.803386] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80471ABC | umac branchlink2
[ 1033.803389] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0081954 | umac interruptlink1
[ 1033.803391] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[ 1033.803394] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000027 | umac data1
[ 1033.803396] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | umac data2
[ 1033.803399] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[ 1033.803401] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000053 | umac major
[ 1033.803404] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE8F84E98 | umac minor
[ 1033.803406] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0406FE4E | frame pointer
[ 1033.803409] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0886C08 | stack pointer
[ 1033.803411] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0046010D | last host cmd
[ 1033.803414] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[ 1033.803458] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[ 1033.803460] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
[ 1033.803511] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00008136 | IML/ROM data1
[ 1033.803566] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000090 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[ 1033.803617] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[ 1033.803665] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[ 1033.803672] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x803E0003 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[ 1033.803718] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00190003 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[ 1033.803725] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A652 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[ 1033.803806] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[ 1033.803843] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[ 1033.803893] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[ 1033.803944] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[ 1033.803995] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[ 1033.804048] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00400410 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[ 1033.804099] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00009061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[ 1033.804150] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[ 1033.804198] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00190003 | FSEQ_PREV_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[ 1033.804249] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x003E0003 | FSEQ_WIFI_FSEQ_VERSION
[ 1033.804256] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x003E0003 | FSEQ_BT_FSEQ_VERSION
[ 1033.804302] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000000D3 | FSEQ_CLASS_TP_VERSION
[ 1033.804409] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC CURRENT PC: 0x80493890
[ 1033.804455] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC1 CURRENT PC: 0xd0
[ 1033.804677] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
[ 1033.804691] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
[ 1033.804801] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW error in SYNC CMD SCAN_REQ_UMAC
[ 1033.804815] CPU: 0 PID: 5129 Comm: iw Tainted: P        W  OE      6.5.0-15-generic #15~22.04.1-Ubuntu
[ 1033.804821] Hardware name: HP HP ZBook Firefly 16 inch G10 Mobile Workstation PC/8B41, BIOS V70 Ver. 01.03.00 10/26/2023
[ 1033.804824] Call Trace:
[ 1033.804827]  <TASK>
[ 1033.804833]  dump_stack_lvl+0x48/0x70
[ 1033.804846]  dump_stack+0x10/0x20
[ 1033.804854]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd_sync+0x1d5/0x370 [iwlwifi]
[ 1033.804920]  ? __pfx_autoremove_wake_function+0x10/0x10
[ 1033.804929]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd+0xb8/0x170 [iwlwifi]
[ 1033.804978]  iwl_trans_send_cmd+0x81/0x110 [iwlwifi]
[ 1033.805026]  iwl_mvm_send_cmd+0x38/0xa0 [iwlmvm]
[ 1033.805090]  iwl_mvm_reg_scan_start+0x30a/0x420 [iwlmvm]
[ 1033.805157]  iwl_mvm_mac_hw_scan+0x50/0x80 [iwlmvm]
[ 1033.805198]  drv_hw_scan+0xbc/0x180 [mac80211]
[ 1033.805323]  __ieee80211_start_scan+0x28e/0x6a0 [mac80211]
[ 1033.805411]  ? cfg80211_conn_scan+0x75/0x470 [cfg80211]
[ 1033.805532]  ieee80211_request_scan+0x30/0x60 [mac80211]
[ 1033.805618]  ieee80211_scan+0x66/0x110 [mac80211]
[ 1033.805721]  cfg80211_conn_scan+0x18e/0x470 [cfg80211]
[ 1033.805813]  cfg80211_sme_connect+0x26c/0x310 [cfg80211]
[ 1033.805900]  cfg80211_connect+0x2bc/0x400 [cfg80211]
[ 1033.805987]  nl80211_connect+0x544/0x730 [cfg80211]
[ 1033.806071]  genl_family_rcv_msg_doit.isra.0+0xe5/0x150
[ 1033.806081]  genl_family_rcv_msg+0x180/0x250
[ 1033.806085]  ? __pfx_nl80211_pre_doit+0x10/0x10 [cfg80211]
[ 1033.806162]  ? __pfx_nl80211_connect+0x10/0x10 [cfg80211]
[ 1033.806240]  ? __pfx_nl80211_post_doit+0x10/0x10 [cfg80211]
[ 1033.806315]  genl_rcv_msg+0x4c/0xb0
[ 1033.806319]  ? __pfx_genl_rcv_msg+0x10/0x10
[ 1033.806322]  netlink_rcv_skb+0x5a/0x110
[ 1033.806331]  genl_rcv+0x28/0x50
[ 1033.806334]  netlink_unicast+0x1ab/0x2a0
[ 1033.806340]  netlink_sendmsg+0x25e/0x4e0
[ 1033.806346]  sock_sendmsg+0xc9/0xd0
[ 1033.806350]  ____sys_sendmsg+0x2aa/0x370
[ 1033.806354]  ___sys_sendmsg+0x9a/0xf0
[ 1033.806360]  ? dentry_free+0x37/0xa0
[ 1033.806369]  __sys_sendmsg+0x89/0xf0
[ 1033.806375]  __x64_sys_sendmsg+0x1d/0x30
[ 1033.806379]  do_syscall_64+0x58/0x90
[ 1033.806385]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x37/0x60
[ 1033.806391]  ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0x90
[ 1033.806395]  ? __sys_socket+0xe1/0x120
[ 1033.806398]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x30/0xb0
[ 1033.806406]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x37/0x60
[ 1033.806410]  ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0x90
[ 1033.806414]  ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0x90
[ 1033.806417]  ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0x90
[ 1033.806421]  ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0x90
[ 1033.806425]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x6e/0xd8
[ 1033.806432] RIP: 0033:0x7fdea5d27967
[ 1033.806492] Code: 0f 00 f7 d8 64 89 02 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff eb b9 0f 1f 00 f3 0f 1e fa 64 8b 04 25 18 00 00 00 85 c0 75 10 b8 2e 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 51 c3 48 83 ec 28 89 54 24 1c 48 89 74 24 10
[ 1033.806495] RSP: 002b:00007ffcdf587ac8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002e
[ 1033.806500] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055c10a9ba390 RCX: 00007fdea5d27967
[ 1033.806502] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007ffcdf587b00 RDI: 0000000000000003
[ 1033.806504] RBP: 000055c10a9bfde0 R08: 000055c10a9ba2a0 R09: 0000000000000000
[ 1033.806506] R10: 000055c10a588d20 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 000055c10a9bf780
[ 1033.806508] R13: 00007ffcdf587b00 R14: 000055c10a9bbb50 R15: 000055c10a9bfde0
[ 1033.806512]  </TASK>
[ 1033.806515] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Scan failed! ret -5
[ 1033.806661] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 1033.806666] WARNING: CPU: 6 PID: 464 at net/mac80211/scan.c:423 __ieee80211_scan_completed+0x31e/0x340 [mac80211]
[ 1033.806793] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm snd_ctl_led snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_sof_probes snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic cmac ledtrig_audio algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel snd_sof_intel_hda_mlink soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp intel_uncore_frequency snd_sof intel_uncore_frequency_common bnep snd_sof_utils snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_bus snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus joydev snd_pcm_dmaengine x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_intel coretemp snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec kvm_intel snd_hda_core snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41_spi snd_hwdep snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41_i2c snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41 snd_hda_cs_dsp_ctls nvidia_uvm(POE) snd_pcm kvm cs_dsp snd_soc_cs35l41_lib iwlmvm uvcvideo snd_seq_midi videobuf2_vmalloc irqbypass
[ 1033.806864]  nvidia_drm(POE) pmt_telemetry uvc mei_pxp mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr pmt_class nvidia_modeset(POE) binfmt_misc videobuf2_memops snd_seq_midi_event crct10dif_pclmul i915 videobuf2_v4l2 snd_rawmidi mac80211 polyval_clmulni btusb libarc4 polyval_generic btrtl snd_seq ghash_clmulni_intel drm_buddy aesni_intel btbcm ttm crypto_simd videodev snd_seq_device drm_display_helper btintel cryptd cmdlinepart hp_wmi input_leds snd_timer rapl spi_nor cdc_mbim btmtk iwlwifi videobuf2_common nvidia(POE) cec nls_iso8859_1 intel_cstate serio_raw platform_profile wmi_bmof mtd cdc_wdm hid_multitouch bluetooth snd mc processor_thermal_device_pci cfg80211 mei_me rc_core processor_thermal_device 8250_dw soundcore ecdh_generic mei ecc processor_thermal_rfim processor_thermal_mbox drm_kms_helper processor_thermal_rapl i2c_algo_bit intel_rapl_common intel_vsec serial_multi_instantiate int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone intel_hid int3400_thermal sparse_keymap acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad acpi_tad mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc
[ 1033.806965]  ppdev lp parport drm efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid cdc_ncm cdc_ether usbnet mii spi_pxa2xx_platform hid_generic dw_dmac dw_dmac_core nvme crc32_pclmul thunderbolt i2c_i801 intel_lpss_pci spi_intel_pci nvme_core xhci_pci spi_intel intel_lpss i2c_smbus ucsi_acpi idma64 xhci_pci_renesas nvme_common typec_ucsi typec i2c_hid_acpi i2c_hid video hid wmi pinctrl_tigerlake
[ 1033.807021] CPU: 6 PID: 464 Comm: kworker/u24:4 Tainted: P        W  OE      6.5.0-15-generic #15~22.04.1-Ubuntu
[ 1033.807025] Hardware name: HP HP ZBook Firefly 16 inch G10 Mobile Workstation PC/8B41, BIOS V70 Ver. 01.03.00 10/26/2023
[ 1033.807029] Workqueue: phy0 ieee80211_scan_work [mac80211]
[ 1033.807140] RIP: 0010:__ieee80211_scan_completed+0x31e/0x340 [mac80211]
[ 1033.807250] Code: 0f 00 48 85 c0 74 0c 48 8b 78 08 4c 89 fe e8 a9 2d 05 00 65 ff 0d aa cf 6d 3b 0f 85 ab fe ff ff 0f 1f 44 00 00 e9 a1 fe ff ff <0f> 0b 48 83 c4 10 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 41 5f 5d 31 c0 31 d2 31 f6
[ 1033.807253] RSP: 0018:ffffaf1880b8fd98 EFLAGS: 00010246
[ 1033.807257] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000000
[ 1033.807259] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: ffff9c93d1d78900
[ 1033.807262] RBP: ffffaf1880b8fdd0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[ 1033.807264] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000001
[ 1033.807266] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff9c93c9ca2b00 R15: ffff9c93d1d78900
[ 1033.807268] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9c9b37780000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[ 1033.807271] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[ 1033.807274] CR2: 00002fd806795000 CR3: 00000006fa83a000 CR4: 0000000000750ee0
[ 1033.807277] PKRU: 55555554
[ 1033.807278] Call Trace:
[ 1033.807280]  <TASK>
[ 1033.807284]  ? show_regs+0x6d/0x80
[ 1033.807293]  ? __warn+0x89/0x160
[ 1033.807300]  ? __ieee80211_scan_completed+0x31e/0x340 [mac80211]
[ 1033.807409]  ? report_bug+0x17e/0x1b0
[ 1033.807415]  ? handle_bug+0x46/0x90
[ 1033.807422]  ? exc_invalid_op+0x18/0x80
[ 1033.807427]  ? asm_exc_invalid_op+0x1b/0x20
[ 1033.807434]  ? __ieee80211_scan_completed+0x31e/0x340 [mac80211]
[ 1033.807543]  ieee80211_scan_work+0x16d/0x660 [mac80211]
[ 1033.807651]  ? __schedule+0x2d4/0x750
[ 1033.807656]  ? call_rcu+0xe/0x20
[ 1033.807661]  process_one_work+0x23d/0x450
[ 1033.807667]  worker_thread+0x50/0x3f0
[ 1033.807672]  ? __pfx_worker_thread+0x10/0x10
[ 1033.807676]  kthread+0xef/0x120
[ 1033.807682]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1033.807687]  ret_from_fork+0x44/0x70
[ 1033.807694]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1033.807699]  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
[ 1033.807705]  </TASK>
[ 1033.807706] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
[ 1034.287864] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
[ 1034.446394] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_UMAC_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x20
[ 1034.446464] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_LMAC2_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
[ 1034.446519] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0: 0x90
[ 1034.446574] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: CNVI_SCU_SEQ_DATA_DW9: 0x0
[ 1034.447736] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: RFIm is deactivated, reason = 4
```

Comment: Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and edit the question to include results from the wireless script

Comment: @Jeremy31, thanks for your feedback. I ran wireless-info binary but text file is too big to fit in the thread... Is there a possibility to upload the file somewhere ?

Comment: Finally after investigations, the crashes seem more linked to a bug with the NVIDIA driver and monitors (I used double screen with an HDMI adapter and it seems that sometimes there is a sync problem causing PC to hang...). I disabled HW acceleration in Chrome as I noticed I had the issue yesterday when looking for a video. Let's see if this changes something.

Comment: To upload, just `cat wireless-info.txt|nc termbin.com 9999` and post the termbin.com link from terminal

Comment: Hi, thanks Jeremy but now I'm sure that the problem is with the display driver. I needed to download the driver on the Nvidia site and the driver is at a higher level than the Ubuntu kernel. Also the problem is with the dual display (via HDMI), I have a old monitor with an HDMI adapter. I think this is a hardware sync problem between graphics card and monitor. I will change the monitor and the cable.